# How can I predict a vector using Varational AutoEncoder?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, prediction, autoencoder

I found this code, and I did not understand. I want train my model to find the value of `Y` but I wont put `Y` as input. Like I want to make the learn (X,Y)
but after learning use `X` to find `Y`
What should I change ?
this is my code:

```
# %% [code]
from keras.layers import Lambda, Input, Dense, Reshape, RepeatVector, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.losses import mse, binary_crossentropy
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.constraints import unit_norm, max_norm
import tensorflow as tf

from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
import os
from sklearn.manifold import MDS
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten, Lambda,Conv1D, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling1D, Activation
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D



# reparameterization trick
# instead of sampling from Q(z|X), sample eps = N(0,I)
# z = z_mean + sqrt(var)*eps
def sampling(args):
    """Reparameterization trick by sampling fr an isotropic unit Gaussian.
    # Arguments:
        args (tensor): mean and log of variance of Q(z|X)
    # Returns:
        z (tensor): sampled latent vector
    """

    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    batch = K.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = K.int_shape(z_mean)[1]
    # by default, random_normal has mean=0 and std=1.0
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
    thre = K.random_uniform(shape=(batch,1))
    return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon



# Load my  Data
training_feature = X
training_feature.shape

ground_truth_r = Y

np.random.seed(seed=0)

original_dim = 32
num_train = training_feature.shape[0]




## Build VAE-Regression Model
input_shape_x = (32, )
input_shape_r = (16, )

intermediate_dim = 32
batch_size = 64
latent_dim = 32
epochs = 100

# VAE model = encoder + decoder
# build encoder model
inputs_r = Input(shape=input_shape_r, name='ground_truth')
inputs_x = Input(shape=input_shape_x, name='encoder_input')
inputs_x_dropout = Dropout(0.25)(inputs_x)

inter_x1 = Dense(128, activation='tanh', name='encoder_intermediate')(inputs_x_dropout)
inter_x2 = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='tanh', name='encoder_intermediate_2')(inter_x1)

# posterior on Y; probablistic regressor
r_mean = Dense(16, name='r_mean')(inter_x2)
r_log_var = Dense(16, name='r_log_var')(inter_x2)

# q(z|x)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(inter_x2)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(inter_x2)

# use reparameterization trick to push the sampling out as input
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])
r = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(16,), name='r')([r_mean, r_log_var])

# latent generator (simplified)
pz_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='pz_mean',kernel_constraint=unit_norm())(r)
# pz_log_var = Dense(1, name='pz_log_var')(r)

# instantiate encoder model
encoder = Model([inputs_x,inputs_r], [z_mean, z_log_var, z, r_mean, r_log_var, r, pz_mean], name='encoder')
#encoder.summary()

# build decoder model
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
inter_y1 = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='tanh')(latent_inputs)
inter_y2 = Dense(128, activation='tanh')(inter_y1)
outputs = Dense(original_dim)(inter_y2)

# instantiate decoder model
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
#decoder.summary()
#plot_model(decoder, to_file='vae_mlp_decoder.png', show_shapes=True)

# instantiate VAE model
outputs = decoder(encoder([inputs_x,inputs_r])[2])
vae = Model([inputs_x,inputs_r], outputs, name='vae_mlp')
#vae.summary()
vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

history = vae.fit([X,Y],X, epochs=800, batch_size=100, shuffle=True, validation_data=([XX,YY],XX))




# Save models
encoder.save("BrmEnco Third.h5")
decoder.save("BrmDeco Third.h5")
vae.save("BrmAuto Third.h5")

# Visualize learning graph, loss, and validation metrics
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))

# Plot training & validation loss values
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Plot accuracy (uncomment if applicable)
# plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
# plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
# plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
# plt.title('Model Accuracy')
# plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
# plt.xlabel('Epoch')
# plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation'], loc='lower right')
# plt.show()
```